# In Dynamics crm the js file can't be attached

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

When I attach js file to form property in lead and save and publish  customization the js file does not run and when I open the form property again it does not have the js file I attach.

[image: when i put the js file and publish]

[image: after publish the js file does not exist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in chrome but when worked on internet explorer the problem is disappear

Answer (score 1):

Please verify these steps and this should solve your problem:

1. If you have multiple forms, make sure you are checking the same form in both cases
2. Don’t forget to click OK button in form properties after adding library/event, then save the form, and then publish. Worst case, do Publish All customizations

Comment: thanks arun the problem seem to be when i work inside the serve it works but when i work in another environment outside the server the changes not saved

Comment: In another environment outside of the server.... So you're not checking the same form you just published? @AhmedMehany